# XmlException in AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I get an `System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing` down in the code, at the line `var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);`

Obviously it is a MVC 5 AccountController unmodified from the template. It worked flawlessly local before I deployed to Azure, where I had some problems. Because of that I tried to check everything locally again, with the result of the Exception, that haunts me.

Has anyone an idea what I am missing?

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

UPDATE: Last Lines of the call stack window

```
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously)  Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)   Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)  Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
    [AppDomain Transition]
```

Comment: Can you provide a call stack?  Without seeing it, I am guessing some form of web.config misconfiguration - such as the Membership section is not defined.

Comment: Is this what you want: Debug, open the Call Stack Window and insert the output above. Sorry I'm asking, because it is a wall of code? Btw, I checked the web.config file and also copy and pasted it from a new template.

Comment: Yes, but you can just include the last couple lines of the stack.  I am hoping to see what is failing inside the .NET code.  The last couple lines should give you context.  Example if the last method called is "GetConfigurationXml" or something - that will give you a clue as to where it is looking.